# Translate column name from one language to another

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible I can translate column name from one language to another.
For example:
In one of our application, DB columns named in polish. 
I want, for example when I give select * from table_name. I can read column name in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the quickest way to do this is to define [views](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views001.htm) (some sort of wrappers over the tables). However, this will lead to extra maintenance, as each schema change in the source tables will require a change in the correspondent view.

Comment: Thanks Alexei but I do have lots of tables, if I create views on each of them, it will lead to extra maintenance as you said. Do oracle have any automatic translate function? or any feature of SQL developer which can help in this case?

Comment: @AlbertEinstein: views are your only chance of doing that

Comment: I think using views in the only reasonable. Theoretically, you can create some translation mappings for columns and pass all your english queries to a procedure that replaces column names. But this is way messier than defining the views, as all queries will be dynamic. Using views look hard, but you do not have to do them all at once. Define views only for tables that you use when chaging some functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Create view on the top of your original table and give access to your users just to the view.  For the end users hide your real table. You can map columns from original table to view column names that will have national characters.